# How can I use Methods of a class without knowing the type?

Tags: java, class, components, jtextfield, gettext

I have following problem: I have a JPanel named activeCenter in which I save different JPanels from time to time when using my program. In those JPanels are a bunch of JTextfields, JLabels and a JButton. 
Now I want to get the text of all the Textfields (amount is known). My problem is now: I use a for-loop to go through all the Components in the JPanel and check whether its a JTextfield or not. The problem here is, if it is a JTextField, how do I use the Method getText()? I only have the Component and dont know how to make use of the Methods from JTextField. Is there a way to fix this without having to save the JTextFields in an array? Here is the relevant code:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for(Component c: activeCenter.getComponents())
    {
      if(c.getClass() == JTextField.class)
      {
        //use the Method getText() on c
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast your `c` object like this:

```
String text = null;
if (c instanceof JTextField) {
    text = ((JTextField)c).getText();
}
```

Also note that you can use the `instanceof` keyword for your `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd go with a redesign: create a class which wraps a `JPanel` and make it implement `Iterable<JTextField>`. Create two `.addComponent()` method: one to add a `JTextField` specifically, another to add a `Component`. Store the `JTextField` elements in a `List`.

The implementation of `Iterable<JTextField>` is then as simple as:

```
@Override
public Iterator<JTextField> iterator()
{
    return textFields.iterator();
}
```

and you can use a foreach loop:

```
for (final JTextField textField: activeCenter)
    // use textField.getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast it to a JTextField:

`((JTextField) c).getText();`